# Trigger textbox bubble event on date change

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling, event-capturing

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

            var lblupdate = $(".lblupdate");
            for (var i = 0; i < lblupdate.length; i++) {
                lblupdate[i].addEventListener('click', OnLabelClick);
            }  
            });
            
function OnLabelClick() {
alert(3);
    $('.updatedisplay').addClass("hide");
    $('.lblupdate').removeClass("hide");
    var inputCtrl = $(this).attr('id').replace("lbl", "DetailDataValueId");
    $(this).addClass("hide");
    $("#" + inputCtrl).removeClass('hide');
    $("#" + inputCtrl).show();
    $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass("hide");
}
function GenerateRow(param1,pram2,param3){

 $("#tblMatrix_89_2867").on('click', 'tr:last', function (e) {
   
 var $tr = $(this).closest('.trbar');
 var currentRow = $(this).find('td:first').text();
 if ($(this).closest('.trbar').is(":last-child")) {
   var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
   $clone.find(':text').val('');
                
   $clone.find('td').each(function (item) {
    $(this).attr("data-rowindex", parseInt(currentRow) + 1);
   });
                    
   $tr.after($clone);         
                
  }
 });
}
```

```css
.hide{
      display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblMatrix_89_2867" class="table table-bordered2 table-vmiddle table-sm2 mb-10 table_form_controls pematrix-table">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                                                            <th>
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-outer" style="color:#8e8d8d;font-weight:bold">
                                        Header 1
                                        <span class="input-group-addon p-0">
                                            
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-outer" style="color:#8e8d8d;font-weight:bold">
                                        Header 2
                                        <span class="input-group-addon p-0">
                                            
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr class="trbar " data-matrixid="0">                            

                            
                                <td data-findingid="2867" data-matrixconfigid="89" data-celldefaultvalue="04/10/2019" data-systemid="455" data-rowindex="1" data-columnindex="1" data-matrixdetailid="0" data-isfortextboxofdd="False" data-celldatatype="0" data-celltypeid="3" data-isserialnoadded="False" class="tdbar no-ellipsis " onclick="GenerateRow(89,2867,event);">
                                    

                                    

                                            <input id="DetailDataValueId_947_2867" style="color:#8e8d8d;font-weight:bold" type="date" value="04/10/2019" onchange="SaveMatrixData(this, '0', 89, 0, '947_2867');" data-rowindex="1" data-columnindex="1" class="form-control input-xs customdatepicker customfield datePicker" autocomplete="off">
                                                                    </td>
                                <td data-findingid="2867" data-matrixconfigid="89" data-celldefaultvalue="" data-systemid="455" data-rowindex="1" data-columnindex="2" data-matrixdetailid="0" data-isfortextboxofdd="False" data-celldatatype="0" data-celltypeid="1" data-isserialnoadded="False" class="tdbar no-ellipsis relative" onclick="GenerateRow(89,2867,event);">
                                    

                                    

                                            <label data-rowindex="1" id="lbl_949_2867" data-columnindex="2" style="color:#8e8d8d;font-weight:bold" class="form-control input-xs ml-2 control-label2 lblupdate">123</label>
                                            <div class="input-group input-group-outer">
                                                <input type="text" id="DetailDataValueId_949_2867" style="color:#8e8d8d;font-weight:bold" class="form-control input-xs txtChildvalue hide updatedisplay" value="" autocomplete="off">
                                               
                                            </div>
                                                                    </td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
```

I have one table. On clicking of last row element I am generating new row to the table. I have Onclick function bind to the `td`.

Now I have datetimepicker within td. 
I am having issue binding date by clicking datepicker and saving the same because it triggers td onclick function.

What I want is to bind date first then save the date by onchange function of input and then create the row.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<td data-findingid="2866" data-matrixconfigid="2" data-celldefaultvalue="04/08/2019" data-systemid="455" data-rowindex="3" data-columnindex="3" data-matrixdetailid="1788" data-isfortextboxofdd="False" data-celldatatype="0" data-celltypeid="3" data-isserialnoadded="True" class="no-ellipsis relative" onclick="GenerateRow(2,2866);">                                
  <input id="DetailDataValueId_1788_2866" type="text" value="04/08/2019" onchange="SaveMatrixData(this, '0', 2, 46, 1788_2866);" data-rowindex="3" data-columnindex="3" class="form-control input-xs customdatepicker customfield datePicker" autocomplete="off">
  </td>
```

**Update**
Here is my Generate row function:

```
   function GenerateRow(MatrixConfigId, FindingId, e) {
        $('#tblMatrix_90_2866').on('click', 'tr:last', function (e) {
          //It does not call this part
        });
    }
```

Now, problem is it comes to Generate row function only but does not implement the logic. I guess it is not capturing it. Will you please help?

What I want is to select date from datepicker and at the same time generate row too.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `event` as an additional argument to the event handler (this works cross-browser, even in modern browsers that don't provide a global `event` object) and check for the target element.

If the user clicked an input element, return `true` to let the browser proceed with the normal operation, otherwise execute your row insertion code.

(I changed the `input` type to `date` for demonstration purposes.)

```js
function GenerateRow(row, id, target) {
  if (target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    console.log('proceed with date picker');
    return true;
  }
  console.log('would insert row now');
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-findingid="2866" data-matrixconfigid="2" data-celldefaultvalue="04/08/2019" data-systemid="455" data-rowindex="3" data-columnindex="3" data-matrixdetailid="1788" data-isfortextboxofdd="False" data-celldatatype="0" data-celltypeid="3" data-isserialnoadded="True" class="no-ellipsis relative" onclick="GenerateRow(2,2866,event.target);">                                
      Other row content, click to insert row <input id="DetailDataValueId_1788_2866" type="date" value="04/08/2019" onchange="SaveMatrixData(this, '0', 2, 46, 1788_2866);" data-rowindex="3" data-columnindex="3" class="form-control input-xs customdatepicker customfield datePicker" autocomplete="off">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please help me with my update in question?

Comment: You're binding to click within a click handler. Is that really what your trying to do? Also there's no element with the id `tblMatrix_90_2866` in your markup to bind to.

Comment: tblMatrix_90_2866 is table id and yes I have label, dropdown in other cell for which I use click handler to enter data to controls and generate row as well

Comment: I think it would be fair I you accepted the answer if it solved your initial problem and posted any further questions as questions of their own. Without seeing your code as a fully working example showcasing the issues you're having, there's not much to go on in order to help you, anyway.

Comment: I have created similliar sample.